# Existence of complement of a subspace without Zorn's lemma

Tags: linear-algebra, axiom-of-choice

Let $E$ be a $\mathbb{K}$-vector space. I have seen that every subspace $F \subset E$ has an (algebraic) complement $F'$  ($F+F'=E$ and $F \cap F'=\{0\}$).

One proof (using that every vector space admits a basis) is found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2067949/proving-the-existence-of-a-complement-subspace-u-subset-v), and another using directly Zorn's lemma in [here](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/algebraic-complements-of-linear-subspaces).

What I would like to know is if it is possible to prove that statement without using the axiom of choice.

One idea that came to me was this: in the finite case, the complement of a subspace  $F \subset E$ is isomorphic to the quotient space $E/F$. Is this true in the general case? If there were a way to embed $E/F$ in $E$ in such a way that it is the complement of $F$, we could prove the statement.

On the other hand, a way to prove that this is not possible to achieve could be to deduce that every vector space admits a basis (without using AC) from the fact that every subspace admits a complement. But I can't see how this could be done.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: There are probably a lot of related questions. Try looking at the conjunction of the tags you've used. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/axiom-of-choice+linear-algebra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a theorem of ZF (provided ZF is consistent).  For information of this kind you may consult Rubin & Rubin, *Equivalents of the Axiom of Choice*, I and II.

One case with no complement constructible in ZF is this one:  $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb R$, vector spaces over $\mathbb Q$.  There is a model for ZF due to Solovay (and Shelah?) where every subset of $\mathbb R$ has the property of Baire.  But a group homomorphism $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ such that $f^{-1}(U)$ has the property of Baire for every open set $U$ must be continuous.  But any additive projection of $\mathbb R$ onto the subspace $\mathbb Q$ is discontinuous.

Comment: The additive projection might be zero.

Comment: Solovay was  the first to prove the consistency of the statement, Shelah showed that the use of an inaccessible cardinal was unnecessary if one is willing to have a much more complicated construction. At least for the case of the Baire property. If one wants Lebesgue measurability (which also gives the wanted result), then one needs the inaccessible cardinal.

Comment: @red_trumpet: note the word "onto" in there?

Comment: Right missed that.